# POSTGRES - Average for previous 4 weekdays

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-9.4

Hi I am trying to calculate the average of previous 4 Tuesdays. I have daily sales data and I am trying to calculate what the average for previous 4 weeks were for the same weekday.

Attached is a snapshot of how my dataset looks like

[image: Sample view of the dataset]

Now for March 6, I would like to know what is the average for the previous 4 weeks were, (namely Feb 6, Feb 13, Feb 20 and Feb 27). This value needs to be assigned to Monthly Average column

I am using a PostGres DB.

Thanks

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: This sounds like it should be a fairly simple aggregate using a `WHERE` clause to filter for your day of the week and then just your in date minus 4 weeks.

Comment: Hi Shawn, I am looking to find average for each of the 4 previous Tuesdays. Could you please assist with a sample of how this could be built. Thanks

Comment: Previous 4 weekdays or previous 4 days of the week that match your given day of the week?

Comment: Previous 4 weekdays in reference to the current weekday. The snapshot I shared has Tuesday as a reference day. Hence it would be average of Sales for previous 4 Tuesdays

Answer (score 1):

You can use window functions:

```
select t.*,
       avg(dailycount) over (partition by seller_name, day
                             order by date
                             rows between 3 preceding and current row
                            ) as avg_4_weeks
from t
where day = 'Tuesday';
```

This assumes that "previous 4 weeks" is the current date plus the previous three weeks.  If it starts the week before, only the windowing clause needs to change:

```
select t.*,
       avg(dailycount) over (partition by seller_name, day
                             order by date
                             rows between 4 preceding and 1 preceding
                            ) as avg_4_weeks
from t
where day = 'Tuesday';
```

Comment: Once again, Gordon beat me to the solution while I was building up mine. I didn't use window functions, but his is a much cleaner solution with them. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4e448/1

Answer (score 0):

I decided to post my answer also, for anyone else searching. My answer will allow you to put in any date and get the average for the previous 4 weeks ( current day + previous 3 weeks matching the day).

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4e448/1)

**PostgreSQL 9.3 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (sellerName varchar(10), dailyCount int, saleDay date) ;

INSERT INTO sales (sellerName, dailyCount, saleDay)
SELECT 'ABC',10,to_date('2018-03-15','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL /* THIS ONE */
SELECT 'ABC',11,to_date('2018-03-14','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL 
SELECT 'ABC',12,to_date('2018-03-12','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',13,to_date('2018-03-11','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',14,to_date('2018-03-10','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',15,to_date('2018-03-09','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',16,to_date('2018-03-08','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL /* THIS ONE */
SELECT 'ABC',17,to_date('2018-03-07','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',18,to_date('2018-03-06','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',19,to_date('2018-03-05','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',20,to_date('2018-03-04','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',21,to_date('2018-03-03','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',22,to_date('2018-03-02','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',23,to_date('2018-03-01','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL /* THIS ONE */
SELECT 'ABC',24,to_date('2018-02-28','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',25,to_date('2018-02-22','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL /* THIS ONE */
SELECT 'ABC',26,to_date('2018-02-15','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',27,to_date('2018-02-08','YYYY-MM-DD') UNION ALL
SELECT 'ABC',28,to_date('2018-02-01','YYYY-MM-DD')
;
```

**Now For The Query**:

```
WITH theDay AS (
    SELECT to_date('2018-03-15','YYYY-MM-DD') AS inDate
)
SELECT AVG(dailyCount) AS totalCount /* 18.5 = (10(3/15)+16(3/8)+23(3/1)+25(2/22))/4 */
FROM sales
CROSS JOIN theDay
WHERE extract(dow from saleDay) = extract(dow from theDay.inDate)
  AND saleDay <= theDay.inDate
  AND saleDay >= theDay.inDate-INTERVAL '3 weeks' /* Since we want to include the entered 
      day, for the INTERVAL we need 1 less week than we want */
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/4e448/1/0)**:

```
| totalcount |
|------------|
|       18.5 |
```